# Add and change a global Id during runtime for Slf4j

Tags: java, aspectj, slf4j

Ive got a microservice pipeline that I have an Id for each payload that passes through the pipeline. The payload contains an Id that correlates the payload to every other microservice. I don't want to manually append the id to the beginning of every log so my question is this:

Is there a way to add/alter an id that will be added to the logs when they are printed. For example...

In a RESTController I would do something like.

```java
Logger.setProps("piplineID", pipelineId)
```

and from that point on all logs that were generated would have the pipeline id in them, until the next request was made.

```sh
// a call to log.info(message) would print
<timestamp> {pipelineID: 123412342, message: <message>}
```

Im using @Slf4j and I am using

```xml
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
                <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX</timestampFormat>
                <timestampFormatTimezoneId>UTC</timestampFormatTimezoneId>
                <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
                    <prettyPrint>false</prettyPrint>
                </jsonFormatter>
                <appendLineSeparator>true</appendLineSeparator>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
```

and `log4j.rootLogger=INFO, DB, console` in the properties file.

I was thinking maybe I could use an aspect to inject the id after the `log.info` call had been made but I don't know how I would connect the aspect to the call.

Comment: There are many variables in your equation, so to speak. therefore, it would be helpful to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub. I would like to reproduce your basic situation and be able to play with it. In its current state, the question is too generic and an answer would be speculative rather than helpful.

Comment: @kriegaex I think I've refined down my question to be less nebulous. Ill open an new question that will be more precise.

Comment: There is no need to open a new question. Just click "edit" and refine this one. Please also try to understand what I mean by the term MCVE. Read the article, if you have not done so yet, please.